# shooting game in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am currently making simple shooting game in python kivy. My character is moving but when pressed space bar, the bullet is generated in the same position. So the bullet is not mapped onto the character.
I tried creating bullet as a class but it didn't help.
I will be glad for any help.
Here is my code:

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Auto,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.rect = Rectangle(size = (150, 150), pos = (0, 0), source = "spriteshd00.png")
        self.canvas.add(self.rect)

    def pohyb(self, vector):
        self.rect.pos = Vector(self.rect.pos) + Vector(vector)

class Hra(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Hra,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        self.car = Auto(size_hint = (1,.9))
        self.bullet = Rectangle(pos=(0,0), size=(20, 5))
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.movebullet, .025)
        self.add_widget(self.car)
        ovladaci_panel_obal = BoxLayout(orientation = "horizontal", size_hint = (1,.1))
        self.up_btn = ToggleButton(text = "Up", group = "smer")
        self.up_btn.bind(state = self.on_state)
        ovladaci_panel_obal.add_widget(self.up_btn)
        self.left_btn = ToggleButton(text = "Left", group = "smer")
        self.left_btn.bind(state = self.on_state)
        ovladaci_panel_obal.add_widget(self.left_btn)
        self.down_btn = ToggleButton(text = "Down", group = "smer")
        self.down_btn.bind(state = self.on_state)
        ovladaci_panel_obal.add_widget(self.down_btn)
        self.right_btn = ToggleButton(text = "Right", group = "smer")
        self.right_btn.bind(state = self.on_state)
        ovladaci_panel_obal.add_widget(self.right_btn)
        self.add_widget(ovladaci_panel_obal)
        # Připojíme klávesnici k aplikaci
        self.Keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed,self,'text')
        self.Keyboard.bind(on_key_down = self._on_keyboard_down)
        self.Keyboard.bind(on_key_up = self._on_keyboard_up)
        self.Keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self.shoot)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        #Funkce už nebude volána při stisku klávesy
        self.Keyboard.unbind(on_key_down = self._on_keyboard_down())
        self.Keyboard.unbind(on_key_up=self._on_keyboard_down())
        self.Keyboard.unbind(on_key_up=self.shoot())
        self.Keyboard = None #odstraneni klavesnice

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if(keycode[1] == "up"):
            self.reset_state()#resetovani stavu tlacitek
            self.up_btn.state = "down"
        elif(keycode[1] == "left"):
            self.reset_state()#resetovani stavu tlacitek
            self.left_btn.state = "down"
        elif(keycode[1] == "right"):
            self.reset_state()#resetovani stavu tlacitek
            self.right_btn.state = "down"
        elif(keycode[1] == "down"):
            self.reset_state()#resetovani stavu tlacitek
            self.down_btn.state = "down"
        if(keycode[1] == "escape"):
            keyboard.release()#stisknu escape a aplikace prestane fungovat
        return True

    def _on_keyboard_up(self,keyboard, keycode):
        self.reset_state()

    def movebullet(self, *args):
        y = self.car.pos[1]*3 + self.car.pos[0]*3
        x = self.bullet.pos[0] + 15
        #self.bullet.pos = self.car.pos
        self.bullet.pos = (x,y) #tahle konfiiguarce umozni jit kulce horizontalne
        #blx, bly = self.ball.pos
        # Check for hit. Ball size is 15. Bullet size is 5.
        #if (x + 5 > blx and x < blx + 15 and y > bly and y < 400):
            #self.canvas.remove(self.ball)
            #self.newball()
            #self.lblRes.text = str(int(self.lblRes.text) + 100)

    def shoot(self, keyboard, keycode):
        if (keycode[1] == 'spacebar'):
            with self.canvas:
                Color(0, 0, 0, 1, mode="rgba")
                self.bullet = Rectangle(pos= (300, 0), size=(20, 5))
                g1 = self.car.pos[0] + 15
                g2 = self.car.pos[1] + 15
                self.bullet.pos = (g1, g2)

    def reset_state(self):
        self.up_btn.state = "normal"
        self.left_btn.state = "normal"
        self.down_btn.state = "normal"
        self.right_btn.state = "normal"

    def on_state(self, obj, state):
        if(obj.text == "Up"):
            if(state == "down"):
                self.timer = Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.car.pohyb((0, 1)), 0.01)
                #self.auto.rect.source = "up.png" # Změníme obrázek
            if(state == "normal"):
                #Zastavíme timer
                Clock.unschedule(self.timer)
        elif(obj.text == "Left"):
            if(state == "down"):
                self.timer = Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.car.pohyb((-1, 0)), 0.01)
                #self.car.rect.source = "left.png" # Změníme obrázek
            if(state == "normal"):
                Clock.unschedule(self.timer)
        elif(obj.text == "Down"):
            if(state == "down"):
                self.timer = Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.car.pohyb((0, -1)), 0.01)
                #self.car.rect.source = "down.png" # Změníme obrázek
            if(state == "normal"):
                Clock.unschedule(self.timer)
        elif(obj.text == "Right"):
            if(state == "down"):
                self.timer = Clock.schedule_interval(lambda dt: self.car.pohyb((1, 0)), 0.01)
                #self.car.rect.source = "right.png" # Změníme obrázek
            if(state == "normal"):
                Clock.unschedule(self.timer)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (1,1,1,1)
        return Hra()

root = MainApp()
root.run()``
```

Comment: On a quick scan through your code, the first line of the `movebullet()` method looks very strange: `y = self.car.pos[1]*3 + self.car.pos[0]*3`.  Is that correct?  What does that do?

Comment: It should have create y position for bullet based on position of the character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `Auto` instance is nearly the size of the `Hra` (`size_hint = (1,.9)`), and your `Bullet` position is based on the position of the `Auto` instance. Your `Up`, `Left`, `Right`, and `Down` buttons are moving the `Rectangle` that is drawn on the `Canvas`, but have no effect on the actual position of the `Auto` instance. So your `Bullet` is always created at the same position (the `Auto` position never changes). One way to fix it is to make the `Bullet` position depend on the `Rectangle` instead. Like this:

```
def movebullet(self, *args):
    y = self.car.rect.pos[1]  # use position of Rectangle
    x = self.bullet.pos[0] + 15
    #self.bullet.pos = self.car.pos
    self.bullet.pos = (x,y) #tahle konfiiguarce umozni jit kulce horizontalne
```

and

```
def shoot(self, keyboard, keycode):
    if (keycode[1] == 'spacebar'):
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0, 0, 0, 1, mode="rgba")
            self.bullet = Rectangle(pos= (300, 0), size=(20, 5))
            
            # use position of Rectangle
            g1 = self.car.rect.pos[0] + 15
            g2 = self.car.rect.pos[1] + 15
            self.bullet.pos = (g1, g2)
```